# window.location.href does not work for Enter key event in search box

Tags: jquery

I'd like to implement a search box on my site. To be more specific, I want to invoke the search function when I hit enter key in the search box. The html code block I use:

```
<li class="search-box">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default search-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the js code block:

```
function search() {
    let query = $('input').val().trim();
    console.log('query: ' + query);
    window.location.href = '?query=' + query;
}

// this works.
$('.search-submit').on('click', function () {
    search();
});

// this does not work ):
$('#search-box').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        search();
    }
});
```

The query has been logged when I hit enter key, but the redirection does not succeed. Any hints?

Comment: Seems to work here https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing enter attempts to submit the html form. That's the default behavior. Thus it will redirect to the same page since your form element does not contain the `action` attribute. You can disable the form's default behavior by calling `e.preventDefault()`.

Here's what you can do:

```
$('#search-box').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    search();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Below is small, better and efficient Code**.
The **submit function below will replace both of your functions** to get the value by clicking submit button or pressing enter in input box. Happy to help:

```js
$('form').submit( (e) =>{
     e.preventDefault();
     search();                 
 });
```